# Deserialized object fields are null

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have successfully serialized my custom object but when I deserialize it this happens:

-Custom object is NOT NULL

-All fields are NULL

I know that I have successfully serialized my custom object because I have read the serialization file and it look fine.

Here is my code:

```
public class Preferences implements Serializable {

private static Preferences instance;
public static final long serialVersionUID = 3358037972944864859L;
public String accessToken;

protected Object readResolve() {
    return getInstance();
}

private Preferences() {

}

private synchronized static void synchronize() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new Preferences();
    }
}

public static Preferences getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        Preferences.synchronize();
    }

    return instance;
}

public void save(File file) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        Preferences tempInstance = Preferences.getInstance();

        out.writeObject(tempInstance);
        out.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void load(File file) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        if(file.length() > 0) {
            Preferences tempInstance = (Preferences) in.readObject();

            Log.e("", String.valueOf(tempInstance == null)); //prints FALSE
            Log.e("", String.valueOf(tempInstance.accessToken == null)); //prints TRUE
        }

        in.close();
        fis.close();
    }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my testing code:

```
public class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".app");
private File backup = new File(dir, "backup.ser");

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("APPLICATION", "START");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(this instanceof ActivityLogin) {
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        Preferences.getInstance().load(backup);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();

    try {
        backup.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Preferences.getInstance().save(backup);

    Log.e("APPLICATION", "STOP");
}
```

}

Any thoughts on what might be a problem?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the read object. Your load method should be static, and should return the deserialized instance. `instance` and `this` are two different, unrelated objects.

Comment: I am doing something with instance object after load() is finished, but in load() instance is not null while all its fields are null. Please see my edit. @JBNizet

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the error. We have no idea of what you're serializing and deserializing.

Comment: @fabian I have fixed that, but same problem. See my edit.

Comment: @JBNizet Complete code posted.

Comment: No, not complete. Post your main method testing the code.

Comment: @JBNizet I use Log.e() to see null check result. Log.e() is in load() after reading object.

Comment: That I can see in the code. What I can't see is your main method. The one I can imagine does NOT reproduce your problem. I think I can guess what you're doing, but I wouldn't have to if you told.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132857/discussion-between-jelic98-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this method in your class:

```
protected Object readResolve() {
    return getInstance();
}
```

This tells the serialization mechanism: whenever you deserialize a Preferences instance, replace it by the one returned by `getInstance()`. So, if youc call load() and the instance of your Preferences has a null accessToken, then the deserialized preferences will have a null accessToken too, since they are the same object.

Add

```
System.out.println(tempInstance == this);
```

to your logging statements (or whatever you use in android to log), and you'll see.

Comment: Yes. But I would also stop using the awful singleton anti-pattern. Just make the load method static, make it return the deserialized Preferences, and store it in a variable.

Comment: I have made the load method static and made it return Preferences object. What if I create setInstance() that sets instance filed and pass load() as a parameter.

Comment: I have create setInstance() like I said above and followed you advice and fields are not null. I would also like to learn some alternative to Singleton pattern/Global class. Thank you so much!